# How pagination works in api system (frontend is angular2 and backend is laravel5.4)?

Tags: angular, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, angular2-services

I have a project for hotel bookings, frontend is created using angular2 and backend is created using laravel, It is an API system. I have a table listing in angular2. For that, I have fetched bookings data from laravel and binded inside angular table but I don't know how pagination works through api. Initially I fetched and binded only 15 data. How can access more data when we click on next page. Here is the code for laravel angular.

**Laravel**

```
public function index()
{
   $bookings = Booking::where('is_delete', 0)
            ->paginate(15);

   return response()->json(['bookingDetails' => $bookings], 200);
}
```

**Angular2**

**booking.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Bookings } from './booking';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class BookingService {
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    private _url: string = 'http://cabinapi.app/api/bookings/';
    /*private _url: string = 'apidata/testData.json';*/
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getBooking(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this._url)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json().bookingDetails.data as Bookings[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

**booking.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { BookingService } from './booking.service';
import { Bookings } from './booking';
@Component({
    selector: 'booking',
    templateUrl: './booking.component.html'
})
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {
    bookings: Bookings[];
    constructor(private employeeService: BookingService) {}
    getBooking(): void {
        /*this.employeeService.getEmployee().then(employees => this.employees = employees);*/
        this.employeeService.getBooking().subscribe(bookings => this.bookings = bookings);
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getBooking();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(function() {
                $("#dataTable").DataTable();
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to build a paginating Angular UI that works with the native Laravel pagination system:

First, to help, create a `Booking` and `PaginatedBooking` class (My bookings are simple and only have a description -- customize as needed):

**booking.model.ts**:

```
export class Booking {
  id: number;
  description: string;
}
```

**paginated-booking.model.ts**:
*represents the pagination data returned by Laravel*

```
import { Booking } from './booking.model'

export class PaginatedBooking {
  current_page: number;
  data: Booking[];
  from: number;
  last_page: number;
  next_page_url: string;
  path: string;
  per_page: number;
  prev_page_url: string;
  to: number;
  total: number;
}
```

Then create your service to fetch the paginated booking data. Add a `getBookingsAtUrl(url)` function -- we'll use it later to request specific sets of pagination data from Laravel when you hit the prev/next buttons:

**booking.service.ts**

```
export class BookingService {
    private bookingUrl: string = '/api/bookings'
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getBookings(): Promise<PaginatedBooking>{
        return this.http.get(this.bookingUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as PaginatedBooking)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getBookingsAtUrl(url: string): Promise<PaginatedBooking>{
        return this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as PaginatedBooking)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

In your component, implement `ngOnInit()` to get your initial booking data. Then implement a `getPrev()` function and a `nextPage()` function that call the Bookings service when those buttons are hit:

**booking.component.ts**:

```
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {
  bookings:PaginatedBooking;
  constructor(private service: NativeBookingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getBookings().then(bookings=>this.bookings = bookings);
  }

  prevPage() {
    this.service.getBookingsAtUrl(this.bookings.prev_page_url).then(bookings=>this.bookings = bookings);
  }

  nextPage() {
    this.service.getBookingsAtUrl(this.bookings.next_page_url).then(bookings=>this.bookings = bookings);
  }
}
```

Finally, your component template:

**booking.component.html:**

```
<div *ngIf="bookings">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let booking of bookings.data">{{booking.description}}</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Showing booking {{bookings.from}} to {{bookings.to}} of {{bookings.total}}</p>
  <p>Page {{bookings.current_page}} of {{bookings.last_page}}</p>
  <button (click)="prevPage()" [disabled]="!bookings.prev_page_url" >Prev</button>
  <button (click)="nextPage()" [disabled]="!bookings.next_page_url">Next</button> 
</div>
```

And that should do it. I've omitted some imports for brevity. Customize your template as needed.
I have a sample project here that demos how it all comes together, but note my Angular files are named slightly differently and I've added a naive loading state:

https://github.com/SpaceFozzy/laravel-angular-pagination

And you can [see the live demo here.](http://demo1.robotmonster.ca/laravel-angular/basic-pagination)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The Laravel paginator result classes implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable` Interface contract and expose the toJson method, so it's very easy to convert your pagination results to JSON,
You can simply return from controller

```
public function index()
{
   $bookings = Booking::where('is_delete', 0)
            ->paginate(15);

   return $bookings;
}
```

And result should be something like this

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "next_page_url": "http://example.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Result Object
        },
        {
            // Result Object
        }
   ]
}
```

And you simply can implement your pagination flow in frontend.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes response is getting like you mentioned. But my doubt is how it works in frontend as per my code mentioned in my question.